# Comando composer abre nueva ventana cmd

Tags: php, laravel, cmd

En la consola de windows 7 , cada vez que ejecuto un comando en la consola, se abre una nueva ventana para ejecutarlo y al dar el resultado correspondiente se cierra automaticamente.

Ejemplo:

```
composer search paquete
```

se abre una nueva ventana pero no puedo ver los paquetes encontrados ya que la ventana se cierra sin darme chance de ver los resultados. Igualmente me pasa con los comandos de artisan (laravel).

Posiblemente la solucion sea sencilla pero no logro resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes redirigir la salida a un fichero.

```
composer search paquete >> busqueda.txt
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, probare esa opcion, aunque no seria lo ideal mostrar la respuesta en un archivo txt, sino directamente en la consola.